# Put razor for-loop with indexed property into html partial

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Is it possible to put this razor html view into a partial view or render with html.partial("partial") Or how can I do it if possible, without breaking the indexing of each field that the default model binder can still do its job correctly?

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.People.Count; i++)
{
  <tr>
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.People[i].ProductId)
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.People[i].Name)
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.People[i].Description)                       
    <td>
      @if (hasMoreThanOnePeople)
      {
        @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.People[i].IsSelected)
      }
      else
      {
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.People[i].IsSelected, new { Value = "true" })
      }
    </td>
    <td>
      @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.People[i].Name)
    </td>
    <td>
      @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.People[i].Description)
    </td>                       
  </tr>
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct usage is to use an custom `EditorTemplate` for your type. Assuming your class is named `Person`, then

In `Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/Person.cshtml` (note the file name must match the class name)

```
@model YourAssembly.Person
<tr>
  <td>
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.ProductId)
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Name)
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Description)
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.IsSelected)
  </td>
  <td>
    @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.People[i].Name)
  </td>
  <td>
    @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.People[i].Description)
  </td>
<tr>
```

Then in the main view

```
@model YourModel
@using(Html.BeginForm())
{
  <table>
    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.People)
  </table>
  ...
}
```

The `EditorFor()` method is smart enough to render a collection with indexers

Side notes:

1. To make the `EditorTemplate` specific to a controller, you can
   create the file in
   `Views/YourControllerName/EditorTemplates/Person.cshtml`
2. An input is not a valid child of a `<tr>` element. Place the inputs
   inside a `<td>` tag.
3. Do not attempt to set the `value` attribute in a helper. Html
   helpers are designed to bind to your model. Instead, if your
   collection only contains one `Person` object, set the value of its
   `IsSelected` property to `true` in the controller before you pass
   the model to the view.

Comment: You are right the EditorFor is the correct approach. I used this before but left that solution as my EditorTemplate could not be found although everything seemed correct but that could also be due to the areas we use.

Comment: Should not be a problem if you correctly name the template and locate it in the correct folder.

Comment: Thanks again, I saw we have a global html folder with editor template folder. Putting it there and it worked :-)

Answer (score 1):

Yes. May be you are looking for something like

In the Main View

```
@Html.Partial("ViewName",Model.People)
```

Then in the partial View
u can use foeach/for whatever u want

```
@foreach(var item in Model)
{
}
```